# Implementing a non template method defined in a template class

Tags: c++, templates

When I want to define a method declared in a template class, but that the method doesn't depend  on the template parameters, have I to define it in the include files as :

```
template class<typename T>
void MyClass::myMethod()
{
   ...
}
```

or may I define it in the cpp file as :

```
void MyClass::myMethod()
{
   ...
}
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

You'll need to define your method like this:

```
template class<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::myMethod()
{
    // Method Body
}
```

The reason for this is that the method actually is dependent on the template parameter. Remember that every method has access to the special variable `this`; during the method call `this` is actually a parameter passed to the method. `this` changes in type depending on the template parameter specified during object instantiation and, as such, all methods must be template methods in order to accommodate all forms of `this`.

Comment: there is also small catch that in such methods  a direct dereference of this sometimes required to make sure that included code is dependant and avoid to picking up otherwise shadowed ids.

Answer (score 10):

Well, if the method doesn't depend on template parameter, you can only do that with inheritance AFAIK.

The downside: more code + inheritance

The upside: (much) less code generated, depending on what parts of your code actually are template dependent. In the below example, method `NonDependentMethod` will only generate one assembly while `DependentMethod` will generate as many as there are different template parameters (just one in this case, but make a `MyClass<float>` and you have two, etc).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClassBase
{
public:
    void NonDependentMethod();
};

template <class T> class MyClass : public MyClassBase
{
public:
    void DependentMethod(T param);
};

void MyClassBase::NonDependentMethod()
{
    cout << "NonDependentMethod" << endl;
}

template<class T> void MyClass<T>::DependentMethod(T param)
{
    cout << "DependentMethod " << param << endl;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    MyClass<int> cls;
    cls.NonDependentMethod();
    cls.DependentMethod(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is inheriritance listed as a downside? In which code did you see it as something negative?

Comment: It is not negative, but it does have a bit of performance penalty as the virtual method needs to be looked up in relevant tables. Also, instancing every instance of derived class needs to set up said lookup tables, etc.

Comment: Where was a virtual method in your example? To the best of my knowledge virtual template methods were only introduced in C++20, therefore, you couldn't do that in 2015 even if you tried.

Comment: There is also no need for `using namespace std;` in your code. You have typed 21 characters to save yourself from typing 20 later on, but then opened your code up for later errors depending on the standard library implementation.

Comment: What is it that you actually have a problem with here? I think even my original answer quite adequately explains upsides and downsides of either approach. Nitpicking on namespaces is irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: 1. There are no virtual functions in your code. 2. There is no downside from using inheritance. 3. You are correct, the problem with dumping std into global is not related to this.

Answer (score 4):

Put it in the header file.

The member function is still a member of the class template, and you'd have to write:

```
template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::myMethod() { /* ... */ }
```

As with all template member functions, this isn't actually a real function yet; it only *generates* a real function when the class template is instantiated. So the full template definitions have to be visible to everyone who instantiates the template, and the usual way of doing this is by putting everything in the header.

(Note that member functions of class templates are themselves considered function templates, and you can actually specialize them: `template <> void MyClass<int>::myMethod() { }`.)

Comment: Uh? Are you sure about the note part? That doesn't sound right, for example because you can create a partial specialization of a class template but not a function/method template.

Comment: Oh WOW, it actually complains about incomplete type with partial specializations. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it this way:

```
template class<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::myMethod()
{
   ...
}
```

It's not the method that is templated, it's the class.

You can have a templated method in a non-templated class, a non-templated method in a templated class (your case) and a templated method in a templated class, and of course a non-templated method in a non-templated class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it in an even other way. The method itself may not (directly) depend on the template parameter, but the class to which it belongs certaily does, no? As such, the method indirectly depends on the template parameter too:

```
template class<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::myMethod()
{  //       ^^^ -- note
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen 5 answers and only velis's answer is not garbage. And why everybody repeating back the same garbage anwer. Isnt duplicates illegal at StackOverflow?

Everybody saying that remeember the class is templated. nonsense. The scenario is clear that the function doesn't depend on any template.

So I will do justice by adding the solution that the person asking the qestion wanted. We will declare a static method. Simple!

```
struct JavaObject
{
 jobject m_obj;
};

template <class T>
struct JavaObjectArray : JavaObject
{
 public:
    T getObject(int i) { return (T)JavaObjectArray<void>::getObject__(m_obj,i); }

 private:
    static JavaObject getObject__(jobject,int i);
};
```

Then...

```
JavaVM *vm; // pretend is valid
JNI *env; // pretend is valid

template<>
JavaObject JavaObjectArray<void>(jobject obj,int i)
{
 return env->GetObjectArrayElement(obj,i);
}
```